# How can I show and hide the developer tools with vimperator in firefox?

Tags: firefox, vimperator, developer-tools

Well, I didn't find anything on this topic. Is there a way to interact with the developer tools in firefox via vimperator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what you want to do.

- You can access the `Web Developer` menu using `emenu`.

  For instance, to bind <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> to open the Browser Console, add this to your .vimperatorrc:

  ```
  nnoremap gc :emenu Tools.Web Developer.Browser Console<CR>
  ```

  or to define a command `:bc` to do so, use:

  ```
  command! bc -description "Open the browser console" :emenu Tools.Web Developer.Browser Console<CR>
  ```
- If there's already a hotkey for an action, you can define a command or another key binding to access it.

  For example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> toggles the developer tools. So I can define a command `dev` and a binding <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> with the following:

  ```
  command! dev -description "Toggle developer tools" :normal <C-S-i>
  nnoremap gd <C-S-i>
  ```